# Does '\0' Take Up The Size of a Char? - C

Tags: c, null-terminated

So I am creating a char to string converter and I am creating a string using `malloc`. I know I need to make space for the null terminating character `\0`. So do I do `char *example = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);` (i.e. `\0` takes up 1 byte) or `char *example = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));` (i.e. `\0` takes up the size of a char). So how much space does `\0` take up?

**Edit:** I just realized that it's the same, thank you to all!

Comment: Those are equivalent, because `sizeof(char) == 1` (always).

Comment: thanks i forgot about that ‍♂️ ( :

Comment: Also, the null terminator *is* a char.

Comment: (Just don't do `sizeof('\0')`, because bizarrely, character literals are not chars.)

Comment: `'\0'` is a _character constant_.  It has type `int` and its size is `sizeof(int)`.  `char ch = '\0';` assigned the value of 0 to `ch`.  Size of `ch` is  `sizeof(ch)` or 1.

Comment: I know this question is tagged "C", but just so someone doesn't get thrown off in C++, in C++ `sizeof('\0') ==1` (unlike C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'\0'` takes up one byte of space. You probably want to `malloc(length_of_string + 1)`

So for `"abc"`, you would allocate a total of 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the question once the annoying 11 minute timer is up

Answer (score 3):

Just to underline something that was pointed out in the comments:

> [does] `'\0'` take up 1 byte [or does it] take up the size of a `char`

These are the same thing, because a `char` is one byte **by definition**.  `sizeof(char) == 1` will always be true, no matter what your implementation of C is.

The idiomatic way to write your `malloc` call is

```
malloc(1 + 1);  /* one character, + terminating NUL */
```

The only time you should ever write `sizeof(char)` in your code, is if you need to force an expression to have type `size_t`, but you can't include `stddef.h` for some bizarre reason.

(It is possible, although very unlikely, for a `char` to be bigger than one *octet*—that is, for it to contain more than eight bits.  For instance, a C implementation for the PDP-10 would probably make `char` contain nine bits, and there have been word-oriented processors where `char` had to be 16 or 32 bits.  On such implementations, `sizeof(char)` is *still* 1, and a `char` is still considered to be the same thing as a "byte", but the macro `CHAR_BIT` (defined in `limits.h`) will have a value larger than 8.

(It is *not* possible for `char` to contain *fewer* than eight bits, because a `char` is required to be able to represent the numeric range −127 ≤ x ≤ +127, which does not fit in seven bits.)

Comment: Absolutely `sizeof(char)` is the unit by which object sizes are measured in C, and that can be more than 8 bits.  Taking that as the definition of "byte" is more controversial, however.  Perhaps that was well accepted at one time, but I daresay that these days, a large proportion of the computing world takes "byte" to be synonymous with "octet".  +1 all the same.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed nowadays many people take "byte" to be synonymous with "octet", but the definition I gave is the one used in the C standard.  See §[3.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.6) and 3.7.